# How to receive a list of all filtered items usind jpList - jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm working with the jpList - Plugin.

Link: http://jplist.no81no.com/start-here.html

I'm filtering an unordered-list  with, lets say 100 list-items.
The jpList filters 25 items for example and displays 5 items per page.
With the 'Redraw Callback' function (http://jplist.no81no.com/html/js-settings.html#redraw-callback-function), I easily can get a list of all 200 items or the 5 items displayed on the page but I didn't figured out how to receive a list of the 25 filtered items.

Example code:

```
// create jplist 
$('#content-area').jplist({
    restore_event: 'jplist_restore',
    items_box: '.list',
    item_path: '.list-item',
    panel_path: '.jpanel',
    redraw_callback: function (collection, $dataview, statuses) {
        // ???
    }
});
```

any ideas?